# Error: User Rejected when trying to do connection to Core.app wallet extension on the web browser

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I cant configure out why it tells me contract is not defined whenever I call the handleClick function.

Heres the code:

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { ABI, ADDRESS } from "../contract";
console.log("ABI from contract");
console.log(ABI);
console.log("address from contract");
console.log(ADDRESS);
console.log("Web3Modal import");
console.log(Web3Modal);

const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState("");
  const [contract, setContract] = useState("");
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState({
    status: false,
    type: "info",
    message: "",
  });

  // Set the wallet address to the state
  const updateCurrentWalletAddress = async () => {
    const accounts = await window?.ethereum?.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });

    if (accounts) setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateCurrentWalletAddress();

    window?.ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", updateCurrentWalletAddress);
  }, []);

  //* Set the smart contract and provider to the state
  useEffect(() => {
    const setSmartContractAndProvider = async () => {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      console.log("web3Modal");
      console.log(web3Modal);
      // ERROR HERE
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      console.log("connection");
      console.log(connection);
      const newProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = newProvider.getSigner();
      const newContract = new ethers.Contract(ADDRESS, ABI, signer);

      setProvider(newProvider);
      setContract(newContract);
    };

    setSmartContractAndProvider();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAlert?.status) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowAlert({
          status: false,
          type: "info",
          message: "",
        });
      }, [5000]);

      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [showAlert]);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        contract,
        walletAddress,
        showAlert,
        setShowAlert,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);
```

[image]

Im logged in onto the Core.app wallet and Im using the Avalanche testnet, it asks me for login onto the wallet once I open the app, and then the wallet asks me for login, I successfully login and then it doesnt do anything, it doesnt ask me for accept or reject.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just came across your question while dealing with the same issue.

After some debugging, I found that the error is related to the implementation itself. I got it working as expected with the following tweaks:

1. Comment out the calls to `updateCurrentWalletAddress()`;
2. Call the `updateCurrentWalletAddress()` function inside the "`//* Set the smart contract`" section;

```
...
  useEffect(() => {
    // updateCurrentWalletAddress();  // <- HERE

    // window?.ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", updateCurrentWalletAddress);  // <- HERE
  }, []);

  //* Set the smart contract and provider to the state
  useEffect(() => {
    const setSmartContractAndProvider = async () => {
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      console.log("web3Modal");
      console.log(web3Modal);
      // ERROR HERE
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      console.log("connection");
      console.log(connection);
      const newProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = newProvider.getSigner();
      const newContract = new ethers.Contract(ADDRESS, ABI, signer);

      setProvider(newProvider);
      setContract(newContract);

      updateCurrentWalletAddress();  // <- HERE
      window?.ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", updateCurrentWalletAddress);  // <- HERE
    };

    setSmartContractAndProvider();
  }, []);
...
```